# iframe not properly functional on small devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Following link is publicly accessible and works in all cases fine:
https://partner.unblnd.com/swipe/1?widget=true

But when including the link within an iframe it does not work properly on small devices (developers console - iphone). Visually everything looks okay, but practically positioning is incorrect.

It is included at page http://thewhiskyhouse.com/ as follows:

`<iframe id="unblnd-iframe-stack1" src="https://partner.unblnd.com/swipe/1?widget=true" width="100%" height="800px" white="true" scrolling="true" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`

There is no difference as it is the same link, but how does it come that the iframe does not position correctly and therefore doesn't work correctly mobile?

The problem on small screens is shown below as nothing happens when you click a button, but click somewhere nearby underneath, which does not makes sense...
[image: Visually differently positioned than click events]

[image: Wrong positioning on small devices]

Comment: There are absolute positioned elements in your code (iframe), so it shows the total height of block level items when you inspect it.

Comment: I added another picture to show the mismatch. Visually it is correctly positioned, but clicking a button only works when you click somewhere underneath...

Answer (score 0):

It appears fine to me in Chrome from the 1st pic.  Are you using firefox?  If so, maybe try chrome.
[image: pic2]

I think the issue is going to be the scroll feature on the right, you can change that to false, but it's likely you'll need it.

[image: pic]

Comment: Yes, this scrolling issue is the same as the buttons. It is visually well positioned, but clicking a button only works when clicking somewhere underneath. I added a picture within the question.